Banking for digital nomad / expat
I am planning to travel for a long time, maybe staying somewhere for a couple of years, don't know yet. Basically living the life of a digital nomad for an extended period of time.
As such, the question arises - what facility to use for banking purposes? Every single option that I checked requires residential address and I suspect might at some point request for some proofs of residency at the address specified.
But if I no longer live there and probably am a half the world away, what can I do? There are reports of Wise doing it to some people.
There is an option to keep paying some bills at my last address of registration and ask current residents to send me scans of the bills but it is so much headache.
Is there a totally legal system which gives you access to banking services not requiring residential address? Seriously looking into cryptocurrencies at this point, so tired.

HSBC Expat might be an option, IDK if other banks offer similar.

Generally banks will need to know where you are located for:

Tax reasons,
Compliance reasons (money laundering, sanctions, product/legal restrictions, etc), and
Operational security (e.g.: you say you're in the US but your ATM card is being used in Malaysia. Should the transaction be blocked?).

The last generally depends on the bank, some are more relaxed than others when it comes to travelers. In the US, some banks require advance notice about travel (and some would block cards even after being given a notice, looking at you 4-letter misspelled word bank), while others don't require any notice at all and have no issues with international transactions at random.
The first two reasons are more problematic for digital nomads, because by the nature of their behavior they are... Let's say, very lax about law-abiding. Specifically, tax laws. So countries require banks to ensure the people they provide services to are who they are and are where they say they are (hence the experience with Wise, and other similar services geared towards international transfers).
If you're legally residing in a country you should be able to open a local bank account with no issues. If you're traveling you should be able to bank in your country of residency with no issues, even while abroad.
If you're not a (tax) resident anywhere (or at least that's what you think/want to claim), and/or are not legally present (as a resident) where you are - it is likely conventional banking system will not want to deal with you. Banks in many countries will not allow accounts to tourists/temporary visitors to the country.

I found that e.g. Germany would let me change the address on an existing account to a UK and a US address. They did ask for the relevant tax numbers (i.e. NI and SSN) though and reported to the IRS. Not all banks want to deal with foreign tax authorities though.

Yep, if you're an actual legal expat (nomad or not) there would be ways to support it.
